# angular не корректно работает ng-class с кнопками toggle

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Есть кнопки toggle, при нажатии на которую я добавляю отметку (свойство объекту = 1, например `store.like = 1`), по которой после следующего посещения страницы можно увидеть где находиться покупка (если мы ранее выбрали 'Избранное', тем самым присвоив `store.like = 1`, то кнопка должна быть изначально зажатой при открытии страницы тем самым показывая что товар в Избранном).

Кнопки:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary commonButton" ng-class="{active: store.like==1}" ng-click="like()">
        <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Избранное
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary commonButton" ng-class="{active: store.purchase==1}" ng-click="purchase()">
        <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Покупки
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary commonButton" ng-class="{active: store.plane==1}" ng-click="plane()">
        <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> План
    </label>
</div>
```

Код на назначение свойств, они идентичные поэтому только на Избранное сбрасываю:

```
$scope.like = function () {
    if($scope.store.like === 1){
       delete $scope.store.like;

    } else {
        $scope.store.like = 1;

    }
};
```

Подсветка работает отлично, я захожу снова на стр и кнопка "Избранное" сразу нажатая тем самым показывая что товар в избранном. Но когда я повторно на кнопку нажимаю чтобы убрать его с избранного:

1. кнопка срабатывает, свойство успешно удаляется.
2. класс 'active' не удаляется и кнопка все также нажата.
3. если второй раз нажать - toggle класса снова начинает работать.

Не могу понять почему первый клик не меняет класс?

Comment: как инициализируется `$scope.store`? Приведите минимальный рабочий пример воспроизводящий ошибку

Comment: сделайте пример на [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview), который воспроизведет ошибку

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.store = {like:false};
$scope.like = function () {
    $scope.store.like = !$scope.store.like;
};
```

В хтмл

```
ng-class="{active: store.like === true}"
```

Если не работает, надо смотреть консоль.

Comment: а если значение должно быть `1`? :)

Comment: @Grundy, использовать $scope.store.classActive для установки названия класса, а $scope.store.like как и раньше. Возможно причина в === в скрипте и == в хтмл